# com.android.volley.parseerror org.json.jsonexception: Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-volley

My add item code:

```
public class carParts extends AppCompatActivity {
 ListView list;
 JSONArray data;
 customAdapter2 cust_adapater;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_parts);

        list = findViewById(R.id.listviewC);

        getdatafromdb();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        getdatafromdb();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void getdatafromdb(){
        String url = "http://192.168.1.111/androidProject/getcarparts.php";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new
                Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        data = response;
                        cust_adapater = new customAdapter2(carParts.this,data);
                        list.setAdapter(cust_adapater);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    { // TODO: Handle error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } });
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
                }
```

My CustomApater code:

```
public class customAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

    Context con;
    JSONArray data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public customAdapter2(Context c, JSONArray data) {
        this.con = c;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView nametxtv, typetxtv, pricetxtv, quantitytxtv;
        ImageView deleteimage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // i is the clicked position and is filled by Android return null;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        //initialize the fields in the listview row
        holder.nametxtv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.pricetxtv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        holder.quantitytxtv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvquantity);
        holder.typetxtv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvtype);
        holder.deleteimage = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        // fill them with data:
        // Data is in the json object that was passed to the constructor
        // and we named it "data".
        // extract the object from the json array
        //optJSONObject() is the same as getJSONObject() but better in case the object is null
        // i is the current position, it increments itself
        JSONObject obj = data.optJSONObject(i);
        try {
            holder.nametxtv.setText(obj.getString("name"));
            holder.typetxtv.setText(obj.getString("type"));
            holder.pricetxtv.setText(obj.getInt("price"));
            holder.quantitytxtv.setText(obj.getInt("quantity"));
            holder.deleteimage.setTag(obj.getInt("id"));
            holder.deleteimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String url = "http://192.168.1.111/androidProject/deleteitem.php?id=" + holder.deleteimage.
                            getTag();
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(con);
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    // check whether delete was successful or not
                                    // remember that php returns "success" or "fail"
                                    if (response.equals("success")) { // force the listview to refresh
                                        // call onresume in the acitivty again
                                        ((carParts) con).onResume();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(con, "Delete failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Error:" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    queue.add(request);

                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

so i have been working on this application for the past few days every thing runs smoothly i can send data to my database but when ever i want to get data back i get the error up in the headding
can anyone tell me what is the issue i cant see anything wrong with the code but still its not working

Comment: You might be getting the response as String not as a JsonArray.

Comment: @ali Salami post your output Json format for better understanding

Comment: and how can i fix that i used the same code my university Dr used and i am getting this error meanwhile he is not

Comment: @aliSalami make sure your url **(http://192.168.1.111/androidProject/getcarparts.php)** connection working properly. Are you getting response form that url in postman or browser or anything whatever you used?

Comment: @JatinK. my app sends data to the database properly but i cant get data back thats my main issue